# get a line then have this regex

Tags: php

I am using this function to get all rows in a string that contain numbers.

```
$regex = '~((?:\+?989|09)|(?:\+?98 9|09)|(?:\+?9|09))(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}~';
preg_match_all($regex, $input_text, $matches);

$input = "abc 
for example test text 09123456789 for example test text 
abc";
```

This should return:

```
for example test text 09123456789 for example test text
```

Comment: But... what is the question now? Did you try run the code? Confused about the variable names or ordering or whatelse?

Comment: i need regex for get that line . it work true

Comment: My suggestion would be to learn some regex then. (Hint: not a code writing service.)

Comment: can you hep at this time ? for this question ?@mario

Comment: So you want to get a line of text that has at least one number in it? How does the regex you have relate to the string you want to capture? `/^.*\d.*$/m` seems like it'd do that, this maybe is looking for phone numbers though? Question needs to be more detailed.

Comment: No need to make it that complex @chris85 a `\d+` should be enough to return true/false as OP needs.

Comment: Clarified the meaning of the question